# How to get enumerate numbering by letters, with subsection numbers?

Tags: sectioning

Currently, I am using an unmodified version of the standard enumerate command. The following code gives me labels that go "1.", "2.", "3."

```
\section{Section}
\subsection{Subsection}
\begin{enumerate}
\item
\item
\item
\end{enumerate}
```

I would like the labels to go "1.1.A.", "1.1.B.", "1.1.C." instead. (And of course, that they be set up in such a way that the numbers change in the expected manner for later sections and subsections.) In particular, I'm trying to copy the exercise numbering in [this document](http://math.stanford.edu/~vakil/216blog/FOAGsep1815public.pdf).

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's easy with `enumitem`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newenvironment{enumyikes}
 {\begin{enumerate}[label=\thesubsection.\Alph{*},leftmargin=*,align=left]}
 {\end{enumerate}}

\begin{document}

\section{Section}

\subsection{Subsection}

\begin{enumyikes}
\item First
\item Second
\item Third
\end{enumyikes}

\end{document}
```

Usual recommendation: are you *really* sure this is what you want to inflict to your readers?

The picture was obtained with `\usepackage{showframe}`

[image]

Comment: `enumyikes`!?? yikes!

Comment: Perhaps adding a conditional, so in case there's no subsection only the section counter is prepended?

Comment: Thanks! I'm writing a solutions document to some notes with exercises that are labeled this way.

Comment: Is there any way to get the labels to be left-aligned, like the exercises in the following document? (Warning: large .pdf) http://math.stanford.edu/~vakil/216blog/FOAGsep1815public.pdf

Comment: (When I try your code, the left edges of the labels seem to vary in position.)

Comment: @Potato Fixed with `align=left`. Of course the name I chose for the environment is a joke: you can (and probably should) change it.